# MySQL Warning "User Exists" but user not in "user" table

Tags: mysql

I have been having this issue for weeks.  I have no idea where to look next.  I have cleaned, flushed, restarted `MySQL` service, rebooted the `Ubuntu` server.  What can cause this `WARNING` and the user to not show in the `user` table?  I've also tried to `DROP user` and get `0 rows affected` as a result.  This is frustrating beyond belief!  Where else is user info stored in the Schema and how can I purge it?

[image: ScreenShot]

**UPDATE**

When I grep the username in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` I find the username in the `db.MYD` file.  Although I cannot edit it .  So I know the username exists somewhere OTHER than the user table.

Comment: If you create a `mysqldump` you should be able to find out which tables contain that entry. The command could be something like this:`mysqldump -u YourUser -p YourDatabaseName > wantedsqlfile.sql`. You should be able to view that dumped file with your favourite editor.

Comment: Done .. And the user is not found in the dump ..  However if you view my update . The user is found in the `mysql/db.MYD` file ..

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text you can just copy and paste. Copy and paste it instead.

Comment: While I generally agree with the no screenshot thing, as people cannot copy/paste, and it does not provide a minimal reproducible example in most cases..  In this case, I thought it prudent since I was using a basic `CREATE` statement that everyone has seen/done. Really there was nothing to copy/paste here -- The question as it sits, is no better, or worse off than if presented in "code view" --  Since there is nothing to "do" or to be "corrected" code wise.  IMHO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens when a user is created and granted privileges and then deleted from mysql.user instead of being dropped:

First, create a user `admin_x@localhost`:

```
mysql> create user admin_x@localhost identified by 'abc123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Check if the user is in `mysql.user`:

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user where user='admin_x';
+---------+-----------+
| user    | host      |
+---------+-----------+
| admin_x | localhost |
+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Okay.

Now we grant this user access to db `test`:

```
mysql> grant all on test.* to admin_x@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And check it:

```
mysql> show grants for admin_x@localhost;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin_x@localhost                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin_x'@'localhost'      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'admin_x'@'localhost' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now delete the user *improperly* from `mysql.user`:

```
mysql> delete from mysql.user where user='admin_x';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

And the user is no longer in `mysql.user`:

```
mysql> select user from mysql.user where user='admin_x';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

But when you now try to create it new, you get an error:

```
mysql> create user admin_x@localhost identified by 'abc123';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'admin_x'@'localhost'
```

That is because `admin_x@localhost` still has privileges stored in `mysql.db`:

```
mysql> select User from mysql.db where user='admin_x';
+---------+
| User    |
+---------+
| admin_x |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, when you drop the user

```
mysql> drop user admin_x@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

it is really gone and you can create it again:

```
mysql> create user admin_x@localhost identified by 'abc123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your answer led me in the right direction!  I did attempt to drop .. multiple times ..  The problem was that the user still appeared in the table **file** `db.MYD` for that database (`mysql`) -- So I copied (dumped) the mysql database .. Created a copy .. Inserted the dump file .. I then copied the `db.MYI` `db.MYD`, `db.opt`, and `db.frm` files back over and changed ownership of said files back to `mysql:mysql` -- Flushed, restarted mysql and voila!  I failed to look at the db physical files vs the output of `select User from mysql.db where user='admin_x';` Thanks for answering!

Comment: Strange that `drop` didn't work, I also wondered why you get a warning instead of an error when re-creating the user. Anyway, glad I could help!

Comment: @digijay The OP executed a "create user *if not exists*" statement, the user exists according to the DB logic, so no rows affected and a warning

Answer (score -1):

You first need to grant usage for the user, this effectively grants login privileges in MariaDB:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pwd';
```

Then you can start granting the user privileges to the database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'my_db'.* TO 'myuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pwd';
```

Then don't forget to flush:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: You must first be able to create a user, in order to `GRANT` --  If you had read my post completely, you can see I am not able to even `CREATE` the user -- @digijay's answer was correct.   I was not correctly `DROPPING` the user, and thus was not able to re-add them.